# jquery - datepicker issue - switching date format loses data

Tags: jquery, datepicker, date-format

I am using datepicker with checkbox. If it's checked a date should be displayed in dd.mm.yy format, and if it's unchecked it should be displayed in format mm.yy. After checking it again it should again display date in dd.mm.yy format.

As you see in code it almost works fine:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pola_tresc">
   <input type="text" name="date_from" id="date_from">
</div>
<label class="label_check">
    <input name="mm_yy" id="" value="" type="checkbox"/>
</label>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $( "#date_from" ).datepicker();
$('.label_check').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ( $('label > input').prop('checked') == true )
    {
        $('label > input').prop('checked', false);
        $('label').removeClass('c_on');
        $( "#date_from" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd.mm.yy" );

    } else  {
        $('label > input').prop('checked', true);
        $('label').addClass('c_on');
        $( "#date_from" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "mm.yy" );

    }

});
```

What you can see above is a function that is masking normal checkboxes to make them look better. It also changes date format of datepicker as suggested in documentation. 
I start with dd.mm.yy format of date. Then i click checkbox. It changes my date as intended to mm.yy format. After clicking again i get empty field. I guess datepicker cant interpret mm.yy date format to dd.mm.yy - it doesnt remember whole date in object, it just picks mm.yy date from input field, and tries to recognize it with one of it's dateformat algoritms. It results empty string. 
**The question:**
How can I easily change between mm.yy and dd.mm.yy dates without loosing data?

EDIT:

I am thinking about storing dd.mm.yy date in hidden input field and retrieving it anytime i click checkbox. It should work but it's trick - i am looking for more usage of datepicker. Still opened for any other ideas.

Comment: or maybe commenting e.preventDefault();

Comment: no, e.preventDefault commented doesnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) api to store the full date instead of using a hidden field.